# How to generate traffic to microservices

Tags: rest, testing, architecture, automated-tests, microservices

Let's say I have 4 backend microservices which are deployed somewhere in Kubernetes cluster on some cloud provider (e.g. Azure). I want to test how much traffic they can handle and generate real requests to them. Requests should behave just like a real requests which would come from Client API or FrontEnd application. Is there any existing tool which allow me to generate such traffic (on various endpoints, not just 1 particular). I want these tests to be performed in long time (~ 3/4 days). I know that there is JMetter but it doesn't fully fit my needs. Also bash scripts are not good idea. Do you know any other tools than than? It maybe sth from Azure background.

Comment: Are you trying to replay existing requests? Or are you wanting a tool that automatically creates tests for you give an API?

Comment: I'm trying to generate sufficient traffic. It would be great to create automatically, but it's not a requirenmnent. However, I have already decided to use Gatling, since no one have responded for a quite long time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using a tool like [Goreplay](https://goreplay.org). I worked with a team that needed to do performance/load testing they ended up using this to do the work for them.